# Use python to screenshot notepad

Tags: python, screenshot, pyside

How can I use the window handle to screenshot a running instance of Notepad? I already figured out how to successfully screenshot a widget within the python dialog itself. I have also figured out how to get the handle of the running notepad window. I'm stuck on trying to capture the screenshot of the window using the handle.

```
import os, sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import ctypes

class GuiCaptureWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GuiCaptureWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(250, 100)
        self.setWindowTitle('GUI Capture')

        # console
        self.ui_capture = QtGui.QPushButton('Capture')

        main_layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.ui_capture)

        main_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        main_widget.setLayout(main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(main_widget)

        # signals
        self.ui_capture.clicked.connect(self.capture)


    def getRelativeFrameGeometry(self, widget):
        g = widget.geometry()
        fg = widget.frameGeometry()
        return fg.translated(-g.left(),-g.top())


    def screenCaptureWidget(self, widget, filename, fileformat='.png'):
        rfg = self.getRelativeFrameGeometry(widget)
        pixmap =  QtGui.QPixmap.grabWindow(widget.winId(),
                                           rfg.left(), rfg.top(),
                                           rfg.width(), rfg.height())
        filepath = os.path.abspath(filename + fileformat)
        pixmap.save(filepath) 
        os.system("start " + filepath)

    def capture(self):
        self.collect_window_titles()
        self.screenCaptureWidget(self.ui_capture, 'test')


    def collect_window_titles(self):
        EnumWindows = ctypes.windll.user32.EnumWindows
        EnumWindowsProc = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_bool, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
        GetWindowText = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowTextW
        GetWindowTextLength = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowTextLengthW
        IsWindowVisible = ctypes.windll.user32.IsWindowVisible

        apps = []
        def foreach_window(hwnd, lParam):
            if IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
                length = GetWindowTextLength(hwnd)
                buff = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(length + 1)
                GetWindowText(hwnd, buff, length + 1)
                if buff.value:
                    apps.append({'title': buff.value, 'handle': hwnd})
            return True
        EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc(foreach_window), 0)

        for app in apps:
            print app
            if app['title'] == 'Untitled - Notepad':
                print 'CAPTURE'
                return


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = GuiCaptureWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Use Pillow [ImageGrab](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageGrab.html) module to do it. You might need to move or resize windows (since there is no guarantee that a given dialog is not being overlaid by something else).

Comment: that doesn't help me get the size and bounds of a dialog which i only know the handle for

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/57358/ctypes.wintypes.HWND).